# REST API parameter order

Tags: json, rest, http

I have multiple endpoints of form
`/geodata/someObjects`
and
`/geodata/someObjects/{objectId}`.

Turns out there exist multiple coordinate systems. Therefore I want to specify it.

What is considered the best practice? Should I append

`/geodata/someObjects/coordinateSystems/{coordinateSystemId}`
`/geodata/someObjects/{objectId}/coordinateSystems/{coordinateSystemId}`

or prepend

`/geodata/coordinateSystems/{coordinateSystemId}/someObjects`
`/geodata/coordinateSystems/{coordinateSystemId}/someObjects/{objectId}`
?

Intuitively I would append it, but adding it to the end of every endpoint doesn't look right.

Comment: I would submit the coordinateSystemId as a query parameter rather than as a path parameter, ie /geodata/someObjects/{objectId}?coordinateSystemId=foo

Answer (score 1):

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

---

When designing an identifier with path segments, you may want to review the implications of [relative resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2), which is to say do you want dot-segments to be useful in your design?

```
/geodata/someObjects/{objectId}/coordinateSystems/{coordinateSystemId}
```

This spelling means you can use dot-segments to link resources with the same objectId and different coordinateSystemId

```
/geodata/coordinateSystems/{coordinateSystemId}/someObjects/{objectId}
```

This spelling means you can use dot-segments to link resources with the same coordinateSystemId and different objectId.

---

> I would submit the coordinateSystemId as a query parameter rather than as a path parameter

This gives you a different tradeoff; expressing the information as an application/x-www-form-urlencoded key value pair in the query part of the resource identifier does make HTML GET forms easier; but in exchange you trade some of the ease of dot segments.

---

> What is considered the best practice?

Choose the spelling that best serves the humans that you care most about.